# Impedance matching at the generator side or the load side?

Tags: impedance, transmission, line, matching

For impedance matching, are we matching in between the generator impedance Zs and Zin, or matching between the Z0 and ZL? or both?
Similarly do we add the matching network in between Zs and Z0, or Z0 and ZL?
[image]

Comment: It depends on the values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstances.

If the Z0 line is long, or can be any length like a piece of coaxial cable connecting two pieces of test gear, or is required to cover a wide band of frequencies, then each bit of gear should be matched to the cable.

If the line is very short and narrowband, like the track on a board connecting an RF chip to an antenna, then it doesn't matter too much whether either end or both are used for matching components. We might find that one side or the other results in nicer component values, or lower peak voltages, but generally we get better results by matching both ends.